# Neo4j OGM - negating labels

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I need to form a query using neo4j-ogm (spring-data-neo4j), which is equivalent to this Cypher:

```
MATCH (n:Employee)
WHERE NOT n:Manager AND NOT n:Support
RETURN n;
```

Is it possible with Filters (or other means) from  neo4j-ogm? 
Manager and Support are subclasses of Employee in the model.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for this in derived finder/query methods.
This can only be solved by using custom queries by annotating your finder method with `@Query("<query string>")`.